# Firebase Firestore: How to know if setDoc created or overwrote a document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

With latest version of Firebase Javascript SDK (10.1.0) I am using `signInWithPopup` to authenticate users through Providers and then saving their credentials inside the DB:

```
  userCredentials = await signInWithPopup(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider());
  await setDoc(
    doc(db, "users", userCredentials.user.uid),
    {
      uid: userCredentials.user.uid,
      email: userCredentials.user.email,
      ...,
    },
    { merge: true },
  );
```

How can I know if the recently set document was created (user was authenticated for the first time, i.e. signed up to the service) or updated (user was already registered)?

PS: I would like to avoid querying the DB to check for existing email, as I would need to change the access rules and make all users data available to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point at the root of the question is security: in order to query the db and know if an email (or a username) already exists, you have to change the Firestore's security rules and give read access to the `users` collection to anyone:

```
match /users/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if true
```

❌ this is obviously **not acceptable** as it exposes the system to unauthorised information disclosure

In [this post](https://(The%20problem%20is%20well%20summarised%20here:%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/67287147/1675157%20)) the problem is well summarised and a solution is provided (disabling client access to firestore and passing through a backend layer), however this solution makes you loose most of the benefit of using firestore as a client-side library and firebase as a server-less architecture.

✅ I have finally managed to solve the problem with a simple - yet safe - workaround. I have changed the rule as follows:

```
match /users/{uid} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid || resource.data.email == request.auth.token.email;
```

In this way, after a user has authenticated through an Auth Provider (e.g. Google) I can query the DB to check if there is already a record with that email.

➕ As an extra bonus, I can also handle accounts reconciliation when the same user (i.e. the same email) authenticates through different Providers (e.g. Google and Linkedin)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to know if a Firestore document is present in the database is to query it.

As a workaround you could use the `updateDoc()` method to write to the DB and in case the doc does not already exist it will return an error of type `FirebaseError: No document to update` and you would then use the `setDoc()` method in a `catch()` block to create it.

**BUT note that this approach costs a write each time the doc does not exist**. It's up to you to do the math to calculate the best option for you (pay for a read each time you want to know if the doc exists or pay for an extra write when you actually create the doc).